# PHP and 'variable' mySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I know I do many, many things wrong in this, but I don't have a clue how to fix this (except making many separate queries.

```
mysql_query(    'SELECT *
        FROM opdracht
        where'. if(isset($opleiding))
                {   
                    'opleiding = "'.$opleiding.'" and'

                }

                if(isset($duur))
                {
                    'duur = "'.$duur.'" and '

                }

                if(isset($type))
                {
                    'type = "'.$type.'" and'

                }
        ' gevuld ="nee";');
```

basically, what I'm trying to do is making a query which statements depends on the variables.
This code doesn't work, but I can't think of a way to make it work.
Help?

Comment: @yi_H How could it work? You can't concatenate to an if statement.

Comment: I *know* that. Still he should have posted the error message.

Comment: moreover, add a space after the where. (`where '.if(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($opleiding)) { $opleiding = 'opleiding = "'.$opleiding.'" and'; } else { $opleiding = ""; }
if (isset($duur)) { $duur= 'duur= "'.$duur.'" and'; } else { $duur= ""; }
if (isset($type)) { $type= 'type= "'.$type.'" and'; } else { $type= ""; }

$query = "SELECT * FROM optdracht WHERE $oplediding $duur $type gevuld ='nee';"

mysql_query($query);
```

Set them outside, and then use them inside the query. Also, you should be checking for errors. (I don't remember how to do so in `mysql_query()` as it is very old and I don't use it. If someone knows please edit my answer)

Comment: this code will produce "undefined variable" errors for the variables which not set

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: It won't be an `error` i guess, instead a `warning`?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: No, it's a `notice`. BTW it's bad practice to write code that emits those notices...

Comment: @yi_H I am talking not of these silly categories of error *messages*. I am talking of the errors in your code. Use of undefined variable IS A BLOODY ERROR, like many usual php-ish lame errors. It is not a 'bad practice' but error.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: well you obviously don't care about terminology. well, others do. deal with it.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: If you do not speak the common language it's hard to discuss anything. look, here is an example: I could call you an idiot, then explain that it's perfectly true, because what I meant by the word 'idiot' is that is 'somebody who doesn't care about terminology'. No offence, honestly, I just hope this helped explain it.... Error is something that causes problems. The code above will work fine, it's just a very bad practice because in the jungle of warnings and notices you won't find the real problems that do matter.

Comment: Fixed, I failed to notice that, silly me. Now will set to an empty string if not already set.

Comment: @yi_H I have nothing to discuss with you.

Comment: @Rikudo thanks man. That's small correction but it makes your code usable for anyone who come across this question in the future. People tend to take codes posted here as a source for copy/pasting rather than as food for thought, it's just of people's nature (and the way this site encourages them), so, that's why it's better to post clean and usable code instead of some sketch. PHP is already suffer badly of such sketches, everyone is writing the *real code* in the manner of some bad examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
'where ' . (isset($opleiding) ? "opleiding = '$opleiding' and " : '') . ...
```

or

```
$query = array();
if (isset($opleiding) { $query[] = "opleiding = '$opleiding' and "; }
....
.... 'where ' . implode(' and ', $query);
```

Note: look for spaces, even if your code "worked" it still would have create a query like `whereopleiding ...` and `andduur ...`. Also, please write a small API for your database queries, which checks error messages, shows them in debug mode, does logging if needed and all that stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from what the others said, the problem is that there are no spaces where they should be.

For example:

```
 mysql_query(
            'SELECT *
            FROM opdracht
            where'. if(isset($opleiding))
                    {   
                        'opleiding = "'.$opleiding.'" and'

                    }
    .
    .
    .
```

When this is executed you get ....'From opdracth **whereopleiding** = '

Here's a fix:

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * FROM oprecht WHERE" .
(isset($opleiding) ?
     ' opleiding = "'.$opleiding.'" and'
     :
     ""
) .
(isset($duur) ?
     ' duur = "'.$duur.'" and '
     :
     ""
) .
(isset($type) ?
      ' type = "'.$type.'" and'
      :
      ""
) .
' gevuld ="nee";';

echo $query;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use an appropriate design pattern. Try the MVC design pattern( and possibly a Repository class to store the connection class and it`s methods as well), making methods for different retrieval types make your code more stable and easyer to debug...

Answer (score -1):

You may use following:

```
$opleidingClause =  (isset($opleiding) ? "opleiding = '{$opleiding}' AND " : "" ); 
$duurClause      =  (isset($duur) ? " duur = '{$duur}' AND " : "" );
$typeClause      =  (isset($type) ? " type = '{$type}' AND " : "" );

$query = "SELECT * FROM optdracht WHERE {$opledidingClause} {$duurClause} {$typeClause} gevuld = 'nee';"

mysql_query($query);
```

**NOTE:** curly brackets `{}` could be used inside the string with variables for readability purposes.

Comment: Its not just readability, it helps you separate variable names with other stuff in the string. I find it easy to use curly brackets than concatenating the string again and again.

Comment: @Col.Shrapnel: if you ain't happy with using curly brackets don't use it then. What i was trying is to answer the question using my way of coding.